# Cognito User mark email as verified : "InvalidParameterException"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to add a user to the Cognito user pool. I want to mark their email as verified when creating them, I am using AdminCreateUserCommand here.

```js
    const createUserCommand = new AdminCreateUserCommand({
            UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
            Username: user.email,
            TemporaryPassword: nanoid(10),
            UserAttributes: [
              {
                Name: "email_verified",
                Value: "true",
              },
            ],
          });
    
          const createUserResponse = await this.cognitoClient.send(
            createUserCommand
          );
```

But I am getting following error:

> {
> "error": {
> "$metadata": {
> "httpStatusCode": 400,
> "requestId": "0d75da0d-53f1-44e3-ba20-018c903d2f8a",
> "attempts": 1,
> "totalRetryDelay": 0
> },
> "name": "InvalidParameterException"
> }

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Can you explain how is this related to terraform?

Comment: @MarkoE, My bad removed the tag

Comment: If you set an `email_verified` attribute, you also have to set an `email`. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/admincreateusercommandinput.html#userattributes). No, it doesn't automatically populate the email attribute from the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, as @derpirscher told, it fixed after adding email attribute. New code is like

```
const createUserCommand = new AdminCreateUserCommand({
        UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
        Username: user.email,
        TemporaryPassword: nanoid(10),
        UserAttributes: [
          {
            Name: "email",
            Value: user.email,
          },
          {
            Name: "email_verified",
            Value: "true",
          },
        ],
      });
```

Thanks